Nuxt: [worker reload] [worker init] Cannot find package '~' imported from
I am having weird javascript errors in a row.
import View from "~/server/models/ViewModel.js";
this command failing in nuxt startup,
It started erroring fully random, the '@' alias also not working.
The file im trying to import is basic mongoose schema with export default
Nuxt: [worker reload] [worker init] Cannot find package '~' imported from ...file
I have tried to install different node versions (22, 18, 16), cleared nuxt cache, cleared node modules, i tried everything.
Full error.
npm version: 9.8.1
node version:v18.18.1
I also tried to include this to nuxt.config.ts but no luck
alias: {
   "@": "./",
   "~": "./",
 },

But in this case other plugins are failing to resolve absolute path!
 ERROR  [worker reload] [worker init] Cannot find package '~' imported from C:\Users\xx\Desktop\shadcn\utils\security.js                                                      11:44:29 pm  

  at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:496:5)
  at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
  at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:890:9)
  at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:939:20)
  at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1132:11)
  at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
  at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)
  at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
  at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
  at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)

My package json
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mcistudio/vue-colorpicker": "^2.2.8",
    "@nuxtjs/color-mode": "^3.5.2",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.12.2",
    "@unovis/ts": "^1.5.0-beta.3",
    "@unovis/vue": "^1.5.0-beta.3",
    "@vee-validate/zod": "^4.14.7",
    "@vueuse/core": "^11.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.5",
    "backblaze-b2": "^1.7.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "cloudinary": "^2.5.1",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "embla-carousel-vue": "^8.5.1",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "is-mobile": "^5.0.0",
    "lucide-vue-next": "^0.460.0",
    "npm": "^10.9.1",
    "nuxt": "^3.14.1592",
    "nuxt-mongoose": "^1.0.6",
    "pinia": "^2.2.6",
    "pinia-plugin-persistedstate": "^4.1.3",
    "radix-vue": "^1.9.10",
    "shadcn-nuxt": "^0.11.3",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.4",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "v-calendar": "^3.1.2",
    "vaul-vue": "^0.2.0",
    "vee-validate": "^4.14.7",
    "vue": "latest",
    "vue-router": "latest",
    "yup": "^1.4.0",
    "zod": "^3.23.8"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "nitropack": "2.9.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@formkit/auto-animate": "^0.8.2",
    "@nuxt/icon": "^1.8.2",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.7.0",
    "flyonui": "^1.1.0",
    "nuxt-auth-utils": "^0.5.5",
    "typescript": "^5.7.2"
  }
}

